# Yii2 dont load all assets after setting baseUrl option

Tags: yii2

I need to set baseUrl option to 'admin' for my site.

```
'request' => [
   'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
   'baseUrl' => '/admin'
],
```

After that all assets did not loaded with 404 error code.
http://localhost/admin/assets/e8a33efa/css/bootstrap.css
How to set correct baseUrl for assets?

Comment: did you changed your app asset url?

Answer (score 0):

Pls add content your asset file, which did not loaded.
also pls check if file exist in current folder:
`/admin/assets/e8a33efa/css/bootstrap.css`. 
If file not exist pls try clear all content in `/admin/runtime` folder and `/admin/web/assets` folder and refresh the page